# Факультативна ли запятая в вводном "и кстати" (после "и")?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, невыделение-вводных

> И, кстати, самое интересное, <это> когда предоставляется возможность
>   обнаружить для зрителя так называемый «второй план» – то, что герой
>   скрывает от окружающих.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**И кстати, *особенно интересно*, когда предоставляется возможность обнаружить для зрителя так называемый «второй план» – то, что герой скрывает от окружающих.**

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Между присоединительным союзом (в начале самостоятельного предложения) и вводным словом (сочетанием) запятая **обычно** не ставится, так как союз тесно примыкает к вводному слову.

**Небольшая правка:** особенно интересно (чтобы не ставить тире: самое интересное – это когда). Например:  ...но самое неприятное ― это когда ждёшь, когда начнёшь догонять.

Comment: Я уже обдумывала ***это когда***, но тогда как быть с тире перед *то, что герой скрывает*?..

Comment: Осенило - пойдёт? ***И кстати, самое интересное – это когда предоставляется возможность обнаружить для зрителя так называемый «второй план»: то, что герой скрывает от окружающих.***

Comment: Правила позволяют ставить двоеточие (раскрытие содержания), но по сути это присоединительная конструкция (дополнительное пояснение), тире больше подходит, в то же время использовать два тире нежелательно.